Is there a model structure on stratified simplicial (commutative) monoids?
$\newcommand\Strat{\mathrm{Strat}}\newcommand\Cmon{\mathrm{Cmon}}$Let $\Strat$ be the category of stratified simplicial sets, which are simplicial sets equipped with a choice of simplices containing all degenerate simplices, and simplicial maps preserving the choices of simplices. Verity constructed a model structure on $\Strat$ whose cofibrations are precisely the monomorphisms and whose fibrant objects are a model for weak $\omega$-categories.
Question: Is there a right transferred model structure on the category $\Cmon(\Strat)$ of commutative monoid objects in $\Strat$?
By work of White this would follow if for every natural $n$ and trivial cofibration $f$
the map $f^{\square^n} /\Sigma^n$ is a trivial cofibration, where $f^{\square^n}$ is the $n$-fold pushout product of $f$. Does this hold?

Yes, I think so. The the paper of mine that you mentioned has an argument for the category of simplicial sets that works in the category Strat.
First, in Strat, the cofibrations in Verity's model structure are precisely the inclusions of stratified simplicial sets, by Theorem 100 in:
https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0001870808001539
Next, the monoidal structure that makes Strat into a monoidal model category is the cartesian structure (on underlying simplicial sets) by Definition 59 and Section 6.4. The weak equivalences are closed under the cartesian product, by Section 6.2.
Now have a look at Section 5.2 of my paper:
https://people.math.rochester.edu/faculty/doug/otherpapers/white-monoids2.pdf
We can mimic the proof for sSet to hold for Strat. First, checking the cofibration part of the strong commutative monoid axiom (Definition 3.4) is easy, because if $f$ is an inclusion then so is $f^{\square^n} /\Sigma^n$.
Now, for weak equivalences, we again use this handy observation of Farjoun that for any simplicial set $X$, the simplicial set $X^n / \Sigma_n$ can be written as a homotopy colimit of a free diagram formed by the orbits of $\Sigma_n$ where each quotient $\Sigma_n/H$ is sent to the fixed-point subspace $(X^n)^H$. The argument is spelled out in more detail in:
https://projecteuclid.org/journals/algebraic-and-geometric-topology/volume-16/issue-4/Localizations-of-abelian-EilenbergMac-Lane-spaces-of-finite-type/10.2140/agt.2016.16.2379.full
The free diagram above takes values in fixed-point subspaces of actions of subgroups $\Sigma_k$ on $X^k$ and each such subspace is of the form $X^m$ for $m\leq k$. The argument boils down to the underlying sets. The additional structure of a stratification on the simplicial sets in question does not affect this argument.
The argument now concludes as in my commutative monoid paper. The pieces above allow you to conclude that the functor $Sym^n(-) = (-)^n / \Sigma_n$ preserves trivial cofibrations, then Lemma A.3 tells you that if $f$ is a trivial cofibration then so is $f^{\square^n} /\Sigma^n$.
Lastly, I want to point out that I knew the argument would work more generally when I formulated Conjecture 5.5. So, if you write this up, you might as well include a proof of that conjecture (but, I'd add now the condition that weak equivalences are closed under cartesian product). That paper on commutative monoids was part of my PhD thesis and I didn't know of any applications of this conjecture beyond sSet, Top, and $G$-equivariant versions. But now I know there are lots of settings where one would like to run this argument, including stratified simplicial sets, so it might be useful to have that proof in the literature.
